# Push notification sent from Laravel is received by Android device, but isn't received by iOS device

Tags: laravel, push-notification

This is my code to send push notifications to mobile app. The code is in Laravel/PHP

```
$firebaseUrl            = FIREBASE_API_URL;
$firebaseApiKey         = FIREBASE_API_KEY;

$registrationIds        = $deviceIdArray;
$notification           = array(
                            'title'      => $notificationTitle, 
                            'message'    => $notificationMessage,
                            'icon'       => BASE_URL . 'assets/images/icon/' . $notificationCalamity . '.png',
                            'body'       => $notificationMessage
                            //"url"   =>$firebaseUrl
                        );
$data                   = array (
                            'message'           => $notificationMessage,
                            'additionalData'    => $notificationUrl,
                            'url'               => $notificationUrl,
                            'hazard'            => $notificationCalamity,
                            'quake_id'          => $notificationQuakeId
                        );

$fields = array (
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'notification'      => $notification,
    'data'              => $data 
);       

//header includes Content type and api key
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key=' . $firebaseApiKey
);

//print_r($headers);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $firebaseUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);

if ($curlResult === FALSE) {
    // if curl response is false, it has failed;
    $notificationFcmMessage = 'FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    // if curl response is success, it has been passed 
    $notificationFcmMessage = $curlResult;

    $result = json_decode($curlResult, true);
    if(isset($result) && !empty($result) && $result !== null) {
        if(intval($result['success']) > 0) {
            $notificationSentStatus = SMALL_CHAR_YES;
        }
    }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

The code base is sending push notifications to android devices successfully. However, iOS devices are not receiving any notification. I think the issue is with the notification object that I am building. Maybe, something to do with the keys.

How can I fix this?